# SQL for current Month and week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need SQL for getting current month start and end (1 of current month to 28/30/31 of current month) in `yyyyMMdd` format and for week too, but week should be from Sunday to Saturday

I used for week start date

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,   SYSDATETIME()), 0), 112)
```

for week end date

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()) + 1, 0), 112))
```

For month start

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), SYSDATETIME(), 112) + '01')
```

for month end

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, SYSDATETIME()), 112) + '01')
```

But issue is week is giving me week date from Monday to Monday and month end date is giving me end date for start of next month (20160801)

The result should be

```
Week from 20160710 to 20160716
Month from 20160701 to 20160731
```

Please help me correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--Start Day of month

```
select replace(cast(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0) as date),'-','')
```

--End Day of the month

```
select replace(cast(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())+1,0)-1 as date),'-','')
```

-- In SQL 2012 and higher

```
select replace(eomonth(getdate()),'-','');
```

--Start Day of the week

```
select replace(cast(dateadd(ww,datediff(ww,0,getdate()),0)-1 as date),'-','')
```

--End Day of the week

```
select replace(cast(dateadd(ww,datediff(ww,0,getdate())+1,0)-2 as date),'-','')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first day of the week is controlled by `DATEFIRST`. Here's how to calculate the first day of the week respecting the current `DATEFIRST` setting, and also the first and last day of the current month.

```
SET DATEFIRST 7 --Sunday
-- Start/End of Weeks respecting DATEFIRST
SELECT 
  DATEADD(DAY,  1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) FirstDayOfCurrentWeek,
  DATEADD(DAY,  7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) LastDayOfCurrentWeek,
  DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0) FirstDayOfMonth,
  DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) LastDayOfMonth
```

To convert dates to ISO 8601 use

```
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT( VARCHAR, SomeDate, 112 ))
```

Comment: Can we do it without SET @Today Date = GETDATE()
SET DATEFIRST 7 --Sunday

Comment: Yes, the first set was a copy'n'paste slip - removed it...DATEFIRST is what controls the first day of the week, Mon=1, Tues=2 etc You can DATEDIFF from day zero like a lot of solutions on the net, but these are really based on the coincidence that 19000101 was a Monday. Different Locales have a different first day of the week.

Comment: Can you please edit the query and make it return in INT format yyyyMMdd and without any SET DATEFIRST 7  etc ?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `DATEPART`, `DateAdd` and `DateDiff` functions:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),  DateAdd(d, 7 - DatePart(dw, getdate()), getdate()), 112))
```

and for the month:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)), 112))
```